# Python pandas parse records

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to parse data that is in a dataframe that eliminates everything that is not within parentheses, and then move said data to a new column.  Ideally, if the parentheses could be eliminated in the new column, that would be great too, but I think either result would create the intended solution:

```
current column                                  new column
/reports/industry(5315)/2018                    (5315)
/reports/limit/sector(139)/2017                 (139)
/reports/sector/region(147,189 and 132)/2018    (147,189 and 132)
```

Thank you, any direction you can give would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC extract

```
df.current.str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*',expand=True)
Out[785]: 
               0
0           5315
1            139
2147,189 and 132
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regex like this:

```
old_col = ['/reports/industry(5315)/2018', '/reports/limit/sector(139)/2017', '/reports/sector/region(147,189 and 132)/2018']
df = pd.DataFrame(old_col, columns=['current_column'])
df['new_column'] = df['current_column'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')
```

With the output like this:

```
current_column                                       new_column
0   /reports/industry(5315)/2018                        5315
1   /reports/limit/sector(139)/2017                      139
2   /reports/sector/region(147,189 and 132)/2018    147,189 and 132
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('.*(\(.*\)).*', '\\1', '/reports/industry(5315)/2018')
'(5315)'
```

The full example

```
import pandas as pd
import re


old_col = ['/reports/industry(5315)/2018', '/reports/limit/sector(139)/2017', '/reports/sector/region(147,189 and 132)/2018']
df = pd.DataFrame(old_col, columns=['current_column'])


def grab_dat(x):
    dat = re.sub('.*(\(.*\)).*', '\\1', x)
    return(dat)


df['new_col'] =  df['current_column'].apply(grab_dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions and pandas `str` functions.

```
df['new_column'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(?P<new_column>(?<=\().*(?=\)))', expand=False)
```

The regular expression says, look for a pattern matching anything such that it is preceded by "(" and ends with ")", and it's placed within a named match group called "new_column"